# MySql Query Join 3 tables with empty rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to list every product in database with visitor tracking and sales info by user id.

Here is what I got so far:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec506/19

```
SELECT products.product_name,
       tracking.unique_hits,
       tracking.total_hits,
       COUNT(sales.product_id) as total_sales,
       SUM(sales.amount) as total_revenue
FROM products
INNER JOIN tracking ON products.id = tracking.product_id
INNER JOIN sales ON products.id = sales.product_id
WHERE products.vendor_id = 0;
```

It outputs this:

```
|   PRODUCT_NAME | UNIQUE_HITS | TOTAL_HITS | TOTAL_SALES | TOTAL_REVENUE |
|----------------|-------------|------------|-------------|---------------|
| test product 1 |          42 |         52 |           3 |            30 |
```

But I want it to output products without sales also, so it should output something like this:

```
|   PRODUCT_NAME | UNIQUE_HITS | TOTAL_HITS | TOTAL_SALES | TOTAL_REVENUE |
|----------------|-------------|------------|-------------|---------------|
| test product 1 |          42 |         52 |           3 |            30 |
| test product 2 |          10 |         13 |           0 |             0 |
```

Or

```
|   PRODUCT_NAME | UNIQUE_HITS | TOTAL_HITS | TOTAL_SALES | TOTAL_REVENUE |
|----------------|-------------|------------|-------------|---------------|
| test product 1 |          42 |         52 |           3 |            30 |
| test product 2 |           0 |          0 |           0 |             0 |
```

In case there is no even visitor tracking data at table.

I have no idea how to do it. Some help needed! :)

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: [**See Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec506/28)

Answer (score 3):

Just switch to `left outer join`:

```
SELECT products.product_name,
       tracking.unique_hits,
       tracking.total_hits,
       COUNT(sales.product_id) as total_sales,
       coalesce(SUM(sales.amount), 0) as total_revenue
FROM products
LEFT OUTER JOIN tracking ON products.id = tracking.product_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sales ON products.id = sales.product_id
WHERE products.vendor_id = 0
GROUP BY products.product_name, tracking.unique_hits, tracking.total_hits;
```

EDIT:

Thanks to M Khalid for the `group by`.  I would write this query with table aliases to make it easier to read:

```
SELECT p.product_name, t.unique_hits, t.total_hits,
       COUNT(s.product_id) as total_sales,
       coalesce(SUM(s.amount), 0) as total_revenue
FROM products p LEFT OUTER JOIN
     tracking t
     ON p.id = t.product_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
     sales s
     ON p.id = s.product_id
WHERE p.vendor_id = 0
GROUP BY p.product_name, t.unique_hits, t.total_hits;
```

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid . . . That is a keen observation.  I hadn't even realized it was missing.